# Count day combinations in the date range

Tags: algorithm

Imagine that you have a range of dates, for example 2017-08-01 - 2017-09-15, and start day (Monday - sonday in numerical format 1-7) and endDay. You have to calculate the number of combinations of this days. 
For the input 4-7 what is thusday - sonday and mentioned dates the output will be 6. How would you do that?

Comment: Is input like 6-2 possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. Any possible combination. 1-1 doesn't make sense so let's say they are different.

Comment: What's wrong with 1-1? Seems to me that would indicate the number of Mondays in the range.

Comment: OK. In my particular case it doesn't make sense, but in general yeah. It might be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you would have these values:

```
rangeStart = 2017-08-01
rangeEnd = 2017-09-15
startDay = 4
endDay = 7
```

I suppose you also have the following functions:

- `weekday(date)` determines the day of the week for the given *date*, and returns it as a number: 1 for Monday, ... 7 for Sunday.
- `date_add(date, days)` adds *days* days to the given *date* and returns the resulting date.
- `date_diff(date1, date2)` returns the number of days between two dates, excluding *date2* itself, i.e. when both dates fall on the same week day, this will be a multiple of 7.

Then this could be the algorithm:

```py
# Align range start with closest start day in the range
rangeStart = date_add(rangeStart, (startDay + 7 - weekday(rangeStart)) % 7)
# Align range end with closest end day within the range
rangeEnd = date_add(rangeEnd, -((weekday(rangeEnd) + 7 - endDay) % 7))
# Get number of full weeks in range, and add 1
result = floor(date_diff(rangeStart, rangeEnd) / 7) + 1
```

NB: `%` is the modulo operator, and `floor` truncates a decimal number down to the nearest integer value.

Implementation in JavaScript:

```js
// Define utility functions whose implementations depend on the programming language
function weekday(date) {
    return (date.getDay()+6)%7+1; // in JavaScript Sunday is 0
}
function date_add(date, days) {
    var result = new Date(date); // get clone
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days); // mutate
    return result;
}
function date_diff(date1, date2) {
    return Math.round((date2-date1)/(1000*60*60*24));
}
var floor = Math.floor;

// Main algorithm
function count(rangeStart, rangeEnd, startDay, endDay) {
    rangeStart = date_add(rangeStart, (startDay + 7 - weekday(rangeStart)) % 7);
    rangeEnd = date_add(rangeEnd, -((weekday(rangeEnd) + 7 - endDay) % 7));
    return floor(date_diff(rangeStart, rangeEnd) / 7) + 1;
}

var rangeStart = new Date("2017-08-01"),
    rangeEnd = new Date("2017-09-15"),
    startDay = 4,
    endDay = 7;

var result = count(rangeStart, rangeEnd, startDay, endDay);

console.log(result);
```

Implementation in Python:

```py
import datetime

def count(rangeStart, rangeEnd, startDay, endDay):
    rangeStart = rangeStart + datetime.timedelta((startDay + 7 - rangeStart.isoweekday()) % 7)
    rangeEnd = rangeEnd - datetime.timedelta((rangeEnd.isoweekday() + 7 - endDay) % 7)
    return (rangeEnd - rangeStart).days // 7 + 1

rangeStart = datetime.date(2017, 8, 3)
rangeEnd = datetime.date(2017, 9, 15)
startDay = 4
endDay = 7

result = count(rangeStart, rangeEnd, startDay, endDay)

print(result)
```

Comment: In the case of 1-1(Monday - Monday) as long as we decided that it's possible you can be given the range 31.07 - 21.08 and in this case if you devide by 2 you will get 3, floor(3) + 1 == 4, but the correct answer 3. Don't you think that it's better to use ceil instead of floor + 1?

Comment: That is a matter of interpretation. To me the range Monday-Monday is a period that starts and ends on the same date (a zero-length period), and really comes down to counting the number of Mondays in the period. There are 4 of those in the period 31.07 - 21.08 (including 21.08).